# Default font-size in summernote can't be changed

Tags: javascript, angular, summernote

I'm having some trouble changing the default font-size of this editor:

[image]

Searching for information I found some ambiguous answers that led to nowhere.Any tip or information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Summernote allows you to customise the toolbar.
The summer note official site will help you with details. here is the link direct to website https://summernote.org/deep-dive/
[image]

Comment: I already customised it when I started and with that 'fontsize' tab I get default 16 font-size and I need to change that.